# IBM IHS 7.0 gzip compression doesn't work as expected

Tags: gzip, http-compression, httpserver

I've enabled `gzip` compression in my IBM HTTP Server v7.0. In the response header I can see `Vary` as "`accept-encoding`".
But when I compare the size of the file that was loaded with `gzip` and without `gzip` there is no difference. I'm not sure if I'm doing
this in the correct way.
This is what I added in the `httpd.conf` file

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css application/x-javascript
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code and change it as you would like:

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so

DeflateCompressionLevel 9
DeflateMemLevel 9
DeflateWindowSize 15

DeflateFilterNote Input instream
DeflateFilterNote Output outstream
DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio

LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate
CustomLog logs/deflate_log deflate

<Location />
    # Insert filter
      SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
      BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
      SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
      \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
      Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</Location>
```